# Array initializer shorthand with optional values in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, option-type

I was trying to initialize an array containing optional values using the repeatedValues initializer and I was surprised to discover the following code doesn't compile

```swift
let a: Int?[] = Int?[](count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)
// error - Value of Int?[]? not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
```

What's interesting is that type signature `Int?[]?`, e.g. an optional `Array` of optional `Int`. This feels like a bug but maybe there's something I'm missing about the grammar. I've looked through the language reference some but have yet to find an answer.

The more explicit `Array<Int?>` type initializer works as expected

```swift
let b: Int?[] = Array<Int?>(count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)
// compiles fine
```

Has anyone else run into this and can shed some light?

**EDIT**

Couple extra working examples with non-optional types to highlight the failure

```swift
let c: Int[] = Int[](count: 10, repeatedValue:0)
// non-optional shorthand works fine

class D { var foo = 1 }
let d: D[] = D[](count:10, repeatedValue:D())
// custom class works fine using the shorthand too

enum E { case a, b, c, d, e }
let e: E[] = E[](count:10, repeatedValue:.e)
// enums work too
```

Comment: Don't know if this helps shed any light on the issue, but if you let the compiler infer the type, i.e. `let a = Int?[](count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)`, it compiles. However, `a` is described in the Playground view as `{[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]}`, not `[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]`, which seems to imply that the actual type isn't what you're expecting with that particular initializer. I haven't learned enough about Swift yet to know what it all means, but thought I'd mention it anyway.

Comment: @Aky Those outer braces are there cause the array itself is optional too, not just the contained type. You can see this if you explicitly add the type to the declaration - `let a: Array<Int?>? = Int?[](count:10, repeatedValue:nil)`

Comment: @BryanChen That doesn't compile because `Int[]` and `Int?[]` are two different types. The first is an array of integers (`Array<Int>`) while the second is an array of optional integers (`Array<Int?>`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Swift 3:**

```
   let pageViews = [UIImageView?](repeating: nil, count: pageCount)
```

**Swift 2:**

```
    let pageViews = [UIImageView?](count: pageCount, repeatedValue: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
let a: Int?[] = Array(count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)
```

for code

```
let a: Int?[] = Int?[](count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)
```

I think the compiler is reading `Int?[]` as calling `?[]` on `Int` (like parsing `a?[1]`) and hence the compiler error. This looks like compiler bug to me.

this also compile

```
let a: Int?[] = Optional<Int>[](count: 10, repeatedValue:nil)
```